# Ruby and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter

Tags: ruby, oracle, rubygems, radrails

I have a query about RadRails and the `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter`. I am using RadRails 2.
Below is a list of my local gems, garnered from the output of the gem list –local command:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.4)
actionpack (2.3.4)
activerecord (2.3.4)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.6.7)
activeresource (2.3.4)
activesupport (2.3.4)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
oracle_enhanced (1.2.5)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.4)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
```

However, when I try to run the rake migrate command the following appears:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the oracle_enhanced adapter: `gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have uninstalled `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` and reinstalled it, restarted RadRails, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you using rails 2.3.4 (last updated in 2010) with the newest activerecord oracle enhanced adapter 1.6.7 that released just few weeks ago.

Try to update your rails to 4.1 (it's also requires update ruby to 2.3) or downgrade activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter to 1.3.2 in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.2'
```

Also it would be better do not use so old RadRails. Try latest ruby and rails in any modern editor or IDE!